# MySQL Procedure with parameter syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, procedure

I have a schema with lists of characters from star wars, the movies they appear in, the planets they visit, etc. Here is the schema:

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `starwarsFINAL` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `starwarsFINAL`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `characters`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `characters` (
  `character_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `race` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homeworld` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Unknown',
  `affiliation` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`character_name`),
   KEY `planet_fk` (`homeworld`),
  CONSTRAINT `planet_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`homeworld`) REFERENCES `planets`     (`planet_name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `movies`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `movie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scenes_in_db` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `scenes_in_movies` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`movie_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `planets`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `planets` (
  `planet_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `planet_type` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `affiliation` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`planet_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `timetable`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `timetable` (
  `character_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `planet_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'Unknown',
  `movie_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `arrival` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `departure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`time_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `timetable_un`     (`character_name`,`planet_name`,`movie_id`,`arrival`),
  KEY `timetable_fkplanet` (`planet_name`),
  KEY `timetable_fkmovie` (`movie_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `timetable_fkcharacter` FOREIGN KEY (`character_name`) REFERENCES     `characters` (`character_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `timetable_fkmovie` FOREIGN KEY (`movie_id`) REFERENCES `movies`     (`movie_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `timetable_fkplanet` FOREIGN KEY (`planet_name`) REFERENCES     `planets` (`planet_name`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Here's my problem:

> Write a procedure `track_planet(planet)` that accepts a planet name and returns 
>       a result set that contain the planet name, the movie name, and the number of 
>       characters that appear on that planet during that movie.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm lost/stuck on how to make it work. (I'm new to MySQL)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS track_planet;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE track_planet(IN planet VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SELECT planet_name FROM planets, title FROM movies, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT character_name) FROM characters WHERE planet_name = planet;
END
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: you will need to use `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` probably. Can you show us those tables structures and probably some sample data ?

Comment: Your procedure syntax is fine. It seems like you don't understand how to write a query that joins tables.

Comment: @sand I added the schema for reference. @ barmar no, I don't as I am just learning how to write functions, would you be able to explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello_ friend.

First thanks for posting the schema of your database it really helps. From it I was able to made this picture:

[image]

And I've changed your code to this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS track_planet $$

CREATE PROCEDURE track_planet(IN planet VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    tt.planet_name as planetName, m.title as movieName, COUNT(tt.character_name) as characters
    FROM timetable tt 
    LEFT JOIN movies m ON tt.movie_id = m.movie_id
    WHERE tt.planet_name = planet
    GROUP BY planetName, movieName;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The code for the function declaration is pretty much the same except few modifications.

The major change is the `SELECT` statement:

1. selecting the necessary columns;
2. seems that you have most of the information inside `timetable` so only join `movies` to get movie name;
3. use `GROUP BY` first on planet name and then on movie name so it will count characters on a specific planet by specific movie

and that's it ...

Hope this was helpful. Let me know if it works for you.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you! is there a way i can chat with you to ask a few questions?

Comment: yes sure, just don't know how to create a private chat

Comment: Yes but too many rooms :). Maybe just ask me the questions here and I will try to answer you

Comment: i have a lot lol i was hoping to see if you could look over the rest of my assignment and let me know if it looks right

Comment: Check my profile there is an email, send me your stuff and questions and I can see what I can do. But I can give you answer at least after 16 hours because right now I'm, going to sleep and I can be online tomorrow night